# How do I change the size of the fluent ui combobox?

Tags: css, blazor, fluent-ui, blazor-hybrid

I am using the below control to develop a form using a Blazor-hybrid approach.
https://www.fluentui-blazor.net/Combobox

I am trying to fit six of these in a single row.

Below is the code. I have tried using the width but looks like it only changes the width of the content in the dropdown.

```
    <div class="form-group row">
    <FluentLabel class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Output Part Number</FluentLabel>
    <FluentCombobox class="col-sm-1"  Placeholder="Select an output part"
                    Items="@OutputPartNumbersOnlyList"
                    Height="200px" />
    <FluentCombobox class="col-sm-1" Placeholder="Select an output part"
                    Items="@OutputPartNumbersOnlyList"
                    Height="200px" />
    <FluentCombobox class="col-sm-1" Placeholder="Select an output part"
                    Items="@OutputPartNumbersOnlyList"
                    Height="200px" />
    <FluentCombobox class="col-sm-1" Placeholder="Select an output part"
                    Items="@OutputPartNumbersOnlyList"
                    Height="200px" />
    <FluentCombobox class="col-sm-1" Placeholder="Select an output part"
                    Items="@OutputPartNumbersOnlyList"
                    Height="200px" />
    <FluentCombobox class="col-sm-1" Placeholder="Select an output part"
                    Items="@OutputPartNumbersOnlyList"
                    Height="200px" />
   </div>
```

[image]

Is there a way to reduce the size of these comboboxes?